# How to pass JSONObject and List<NameValuePair> from Android to PHP server using HttpPost?

Tags: php, android, http-post, json

I'm able to send only either one of them using HttpPost, any ideas on how to send both at a time in HttpPost ?

Comment: Create an object which contains both of them and send that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USE THIS CLASS BELOW :-

```
        /*Copyright 2014 Bhavit Singh Sengar
Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.*/

package com.infotech.zeus.util;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class RestClient {


        JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
        String url;
        String headerName;
        String headerValue;

        public RestClient(String s){

            url = s;
        }


        public void addHeader(String name, String value){

            headerName = name;
            headerValue = value;

        }

        public void addParam(String key, String value){

            try {
                data.put(key, value);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

        public String executePost(){  // If you want to use post method to hit server

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setHeader(headerName, headerValue);
            HttpResponse response = null;
            String result = null;
            try {
                StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(data.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8);
                httpPost.setEntity(entity);
                response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity entity1 = response.getEntity();
                result = EntityUtils.toString(entity1);
                return result;
                //Toast.makeText(MainPage.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;



        }

        public String executeGet(){ //If you want to use get method to hit server

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
            String result = null;
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            try {
                result = httpClient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return result;
        }
}
```

**A simple Example to use this class :**

```
RestClient client = new RestClient("http://www.example.com/demo.php");  //Write your url here
        client.addParam("Name", "Bhavit"); //Here I am adding key-value parameters
        client.addParam("Age", "23");

        client.addHeader("content-type", "application/json"); // Here I am specifying that the key-value pairs are sent in the JSON format

        try {
            String response = client.executePost(); // In case your server sends any response back, it will be saved in this response string.

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```